# how to display woo commerce global addons service without product (Only addons services with Add to Card button)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

how to display woo commerce global addons service without product
(Only addons services with Add to Card button).

I have a one Service page which i have to display global addons service, i also want to add to card button .

Basically i want to give only addons service to user without product.
Below down attach the image of addons service
Thanks in advance

[Addons image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX0v4.png)

Comment: Have you tried overriding `content-product.php` template ?

Comment: I am not tried. I am not sure how to do it

Comment: open the template on a editor and you can see some hooks , using those hooks also you can get the job done . or better search the hooks on `wc-template-hooks.php` and then you need to see `wc-template-functions`  to know how things are working, if you are not familiar wocoomerce, better to find someone to code or search plugin.